# SSIS synchronize two tables using lookup

Tags: ssis

I want to synchronize two tables src,dest(DB SOURCE>> src table, DB Destination>> dest table) using ssis, where any (insert, update and delete operations on src will be applied to dest) 
How can I achieve this  using **lookup** tranformation ? 
 Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's not what a Lookup does. Perhaps you want the Merge transformation, or a merging SQL query.

Comment: the merge worked for me, but it seems slow!

Comment: I suggest you go through this, and related topics on MSDN to get a better idea: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141821.aspx

Comment: ok thanks, is there another way to synchronize tables without merging ?

Comment: You might be able to utilise a `Trigger` on the source table depending on the volume of changes and the frequency of the synchronisation needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take table Dest in the lookup cache and then you need to lookup with Table Src .Choose option of the lookup as Redirect the non matching records. For the non matching records(not present in Table Dest) which are present in Table Src use OLE DB Destination to insert them in Table Dest.

For matching record use a physical table or temp table, use Execute SQl Task after the DFT to update those records in Table Src.

To speed up process try to use [Cache Transform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb895264.aspx)

Also you can achieve same by using Merge by following this article, [Synchronize two tables using SSIS](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jorgepc/archive/2010/12/07/synchronize-two-tables-using-sql-server-integration-services-ssis-part-i-of-ii.aspx)